# sampling from a DataFrame on a daily basis

Tags: pandas, dataframe, random

in my data frame,  I have data for 3 months, and it's per day. ( for every day, I have a different number of samples, for example on 1st January I have 20K rows of samples and on the second of January there are 15K samples)

what I need is that I want to take the mean number and apply it to all the data frames.
for example, if the mean value is 8K, i want to get the random 8k rows from 1st January data and 8k rows randomly from 2nd January, and so on.

as far as I know, rand() will give the random values of the whole data frame, But I need to apply it per day. since my data frame is on a daily basis and the date is mentioned in a column of the data frame.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby_sample` after computing the mean of records:

```
# Suppose 'date' is the name of your column
sample = df.groupby('date').sample(n=int(df['date'].value_counts().mean()))

# Or
g = df.groupby('date')
sample = g.sample(n=int(g.size().mean()))
```

**Update**

> Is there ant solution for the dates that their sum is lower than the mean? I face with this error for those dates: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'

```
n = np.floor(df['date'].value_counts().mean()).astype(int)
sample = (df.groupby('date').sample(n, replace=True)
            .loc[lambda x: ~x.index.duplicated()])
```

Comment: I face with this error:      'int' object is not callable

Comment: Yes, for both solutions. No, I have not set the int to a variable. When I use the following code, it is OK, but when I want to use these solutions, I face an error.    sample = df.groupby('date').sample(10)

Comment: This it the output: <class 'type'>

Comment: Does `df['date'].value_counts().mean()` work?

Comment: Else try: `n=np.floor(df['MainID'].value_counts().mean()).astype(int)`

Comment: Yes, both of them work, but it does not solve my initial issue. :(

Comment: What do you mean? You still have the error `'int' object is not callable`?

Comment: it works. Thanks a lot. is there any solution for the dates that their sum is lower than the mean? I face with this error for those dates: Cannot take a larger sample than the population when 'replace=False'

Comment: Thank you. the code works perfectly. I really appreciate it.